# Why is Simics bt / stack-trace command returning "No current debug object"?

Tags: simics

I run
C:\Users\io\simics-projects\my-simics-project-1>simics.bat targets\qsp-x86\firststeps.simics

I then run "run" and let the system proceed all the way to the clear linux shell prompt. I then run "stop" to pause the simulation. But I get an error of "No current debug object". I would think a simple stack trace would simply follow the %rbp frame pointers backwards on the stack and display what's there. Why isn't it?

```
simics> run
Autologin as "simics" was done on "board.mb.sb.com[0] - serial console".
running> stop
simics> bt
No current debug object
```

(I also just noticed the same happens when I just try "step-out". Which again, I would think would simply step through instructions until after it hits a "ret"...)

Answer (score 1):

I think the debugger is not enabled. To do so, the command is

enable-debugger

[image: Debugging mode]